# vim + ctrlp: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I installed all plugins with vundle include ctrlp.  Until I upgraded (:PluginUpdate) all my plugins, ctrlp was working fine.

However, now it displays `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found` for about 10 seconds before it disappears, only then I can use ctrlp.

How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: Normally, I would suggest the plugin's issue tracker but, now that the project has been abandoned that place may not be relevant anymore. I've heard about an active fork, though, maybe you should start [there](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)? That said, the original CtrlP hasn't changed in over one year and, since it doesn't depend on any other Vim plugin I doubt your problem is actually a CtrlP problem.

Comment: reinstalled with active fork.  Mapped key to :CtrlPBuffer does work, however CtrlP still having same issue.

Comment: Then that's a question for their issue tracker.